# Hide Ribbon in Task Form?

Tags: form, task-list

How would I go about hiding the ribbon in a task form?  I have the form default open in edit mode and don't want the user to be able to see the ribbon at all.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your form is opening in a dialog, you can do it using jQuery:

```
 $('.ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow').css('display', 'none');
```

or just by embedding some CSS on the page:

```
<style>
.ms-dialog #s4-ribborow {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Or as Danny Engelman pointed out in the comments, if you do not want to load jQuery you can do it with pure Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('#s4-ribbonrow').style.display='none';
</script>
```

Comment: Or just ``document.querySelector('#s4-ribbonrow').style.display='none';`` if you do not know or want to load jQuery... Note that you can't use SharePoints own mQuery as it is not loaded by default on this form

Comment: Thanks guys..would I just insert that anywhere in the editform file?

Comment: Yes, you can insert it in the edit form file using Designer, or you could add a script editor web part to the page and add it that way.  Keep in mind, if you are usig one of the Javascript methods, you'll need enclosing `<script>` tags, and if you are using the CSS way, you need enclosing `<style>` tags

Comment: Thanks Dylan.  I added the following to the end of my file, but was unable to get it to load correctly...am I missing something?               <style>
.ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow{
 display: none;
}

Comment: I would add it high on the page, not at the end.  And do you have a closing `</style>` tag?  See my updated answer.